# Division of complex signal by frequency response

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, ifft

I have a measured signal (time domain) which I take the FFT of. I have a measured frequency dependent sensitivity (magnitude and phase (radians) as a function of frequency) which I need to apply to the measured signal. In effect perform a frequency dependent weighting to the measured signal's FFT.
I calculate the complex signal for the sensitivity magnitude and phase before dividing this into the FFT of the original signal.
I then take the IFFT of this which should give me something like the original signal shape but it does not.

Is my method correct?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that could be going wrong here.

**Check your FFT lengths**

If you do multiplication or division in the frequency domain, your frequency domain data needs to be at least as long as $N+M-$ where $N$ is your signal length, $M$ is your weighting length.

In matlab pseudo code this means you need:

```
N = length(x);
M = length(w);
freq_length = N + M - 1;

X = fft(x,freq_length);
W = fft(x,freq_length);

y = ifft(X./W);
```

So your resulting `y` will be longer than `x`.

If you don't do this, you will get time-domain aliasing because of the circular nature of convolution using the FFT.

**Is your weighting real-valued in the time domain?**

You may need to use `conj(W)` in the above, but you also need to check that `w` (the time domain version of the frequency weighting) is real-valued. If it's not, you will get a complex-valued signal.

Also note that you may get a small imaginary component.  Often times all that is required to remove this is:

```
yr = real(y);
```